# \StrSubstitute breaks when an argument contains a MathOperator

Tags: amsmath, xstring

I'm using `\StrSubstitute` from the `xstring` package, and it appears that the .tex file does not compile if any of the arguments to `\StrSubstitute` contain math operators that I have declared with `\DeclareMathOperator`.  A minimal failing example:

```
% mfe.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\myop}{MyOp}

\begin{document}
$\StrSubstitute{a(B)}{a}{\myop}$
\end{document}
```

Running `pdflatex mfe.tex` fails to produce a .pdf file, with `mfe.log` stating

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\@spaces ->\space 
                  \space \space \space 
l.10 $\StrSubstitute{a(B)}{a}{\myop}
                                    $
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.


Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1067 strings out of 494953
 12733 string characters out of 6180978
 173300 words of memory out of 5000000
 4419 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4094 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 14 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 5000i,3n,4003p,244b,52s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

By contrast, I can get the output I want by making `\myop` just use `\mathrm`.  A minimal working example:

```
% mwe.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,amsmath}

\newcommand{\myoprm}{\mathrm{MyOp}}

\begin{document}
$\StrSubstitute{a(B)}{a}{\myoprm}$
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image: output from <code>pdflatex mwe.tex</code>]

Any idea what's going on here, and how I might get `\StrSubstitute` to cooperate with my operators?  I've been given to understand that `\DeclareMathOperator{\foo}{foo}` is better practice than `\newcommand{\foo}{\mathrm{foo}}`, but I need these commands to cooperate with `\StrSubstitute`.

Comment: `\StrSubstitute`, by default, use `\edef` on all its arguments and anything defined with `\DeclareMathOperator` doesn't survive it. As you discovered, `\noexpandarg` will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround that works: in the documentation for `xstring`, it mentions that the commands read their arguments "syntax unit by syntax unit," suggesting that throwing in a `\noexpandarg` will affect its behavior.

I don't know what the mechanism is here, but the following edit makes `mfe.tex` work as expected:

```
% mfe_redeemed.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring,amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\myop}{MyOp}

\begin{document}
$\noexpandarg\StrSubstitute{a(B)}{a}{\myop}$
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output:

[image]

Comment: You should [accept this answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764).